# Emotion.js How to use dynamic style in object style?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, emotion

```
import styled from '@emotion/styled'
import { css } from '@emotion/core'

const dynamicStyle = props =>
  css`
    color: ${props.color};
  `

const Container = styled.div`
  ${dynamicStyle};
`
render(
  <Container color="lightgreen">
    This is lightgreen.
  </Container>
)
```

How do I make `Container` with the object style as following?

```
const H1 = styled.h1(
  {
    fontSize: 20
  },
  props => ({ color: props.color })
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a bad example you've copied from the docs that actually results in the `color` prop being written to the Container div, but in essence you would do something like this:

```
import styled from '@emotion/styled'
import { css } from '@emotion/core'

const dynamicStyle = props => ({ color: props.color })

const Container = styled.div`
  ${dynamicStyle};
`
render(
  <Container color="lightgreen">
    This is lightgreen.
  </Container>
)
```

I'd recommend an approach more like this for the sake of sanity and to avoid props getting passed down to you React elements:

```
const Container = styled.div`
  color: ${props => props.color};
`

// or...

const Container = ({ color, ...props }) => <div css={{ color }} {...props} />
```

Comment: const Container = styled.div`
  color: ${props => props.color};
`
what happens if your props doesn't have color? it is as if color style is not specified?

Comment: @eugene Emotion will automatically discard falsey non-numeric values (e.g. `false`, `null`, `undefined`).

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @coreyward's answer, you could also use a much more readable approach, and do something like the following -

```js
const Container = styled.div(props =>`
  color: ${props.color};
`)
```

Similarly, you could destruct `props` -

```js
const Container = styled.div(({ color }) =>`
  color: ${color};
`)
```